# Does anybody know if there is any project for program PLC with ruby for industrial environment?

Tags: ruby, plc

I am PLC programmer for Omron devices and now I found ruby as a very nice language. I saw there is embedded ruby for embedded devices. I'm wondering if there any gem for PLC, if not I might consider to research on how to develop one.

Comment: Omron only provide CX-Compolet for their PLCs, which is a library designed for VB.NET and C#.NET.  For anything else I think you would have to write your own FINS driver from the ground up.  I don't think many PLC developers are using Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PLCs are typically programmed using the IEC 61131-3 languages. [See here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3)

If you are doing normal PLC programming in an industrial environment, the standard way to do what you are describing is to write your Ruby application on a server, and use OPC or something similar to communicate with the PLC, and keep the PLC logic in the IEC languages.

It is very common for industrial controls engineers to get called in to work on controllers that have been in the field for ten or more years. If you use Ruby to do your PLC program, you could be forcing someone to teach themselves Ruby on the fly, during a plant shutdown, just to troubleshoot some minor I/O issue.

My advice is to keep the PLC languages in the PLC and the high-level languages on the server.

Comment: I believe everything is relative, if we consider progression, Contact logic was designed for electrical technicians to be able to put hands on a PLC, however nowadays I doubt these technicians are only electrical, just consider the evolution and what would be the profile of the new technician in the near future?

Thank you for you info, very useful.